# "BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable" when installing Python 3.10.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, makefile

I'm running into a blocking issue when installing Python 3.10.13 on a server running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

I download the source, `configure` with `--prefix` specified, `make`, and then `make install`.  The error occurs during the `make install` portion, at the point when the Makefile is executing this command:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10   \
        ./python -E -Wi /home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/compileall.py \
        -j0 -d /home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10 -f \
        -x 'bad_coding|badsyntax|site-packages|lib2to3/tests/data' \
        /home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10
```

The traceback is:

```
Listing '/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/compileall.py", line 462, in <module>
    exit_status = int(not main())
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/compileall.py", line 439, in main
    if not compile_dir(dest, maxlevels, args.ddir,
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/compileall.py", line 103, in compile_dir
    results = executor.map(partial(compile_file,
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 766, in map
    results = super().map(partial(_process_chunk, fn),
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 610, in map
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 610, in <listcomp>
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 738, in submit
    self._start_executor_manager_thread()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 678, in _start_executor_manager_thread
    self._launch_processes()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 705, in _launch_processes
    self._spawn_process()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 714, in _spawn_process
    p.start()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 281, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 66, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
^CProcess ForkProcess-19:
Process ForkProcess-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-17:
Process ForkProcess-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-15:
Process ForkProcess-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-12:
Process ForkProcess-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process ForkProcess-4:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 103, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function _exit_function at 0x6ae9377b52d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 357, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 43, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt:
Process ForkProcess-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-11:
Process ForkProcess-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-7:
Process ForkProcess-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-18:
Process ForkProcess-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkProcess-16:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/home/dh_2i85ds/opt/python-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
make: [Makefile:1551: libinstall] Error 1 (ignored)
```

**Edit**: The soft and hard max user processes limit is 2061293:

```
[dh_2i85ds@pdx1-shared-a1-08:~/Python-3.10.13]$ ulimit -aH | grep "\-u"
max user processes              (-u) 2061293
[dh_2i85ds@pdx1-shared-a1-08:~/Python-3.10.13]$ ulimit -aS | grep "\-u"
max user processes              (-u) 2061293
```

Comment: Error seems to come off from fork() -- Issue could be *nproc* value - explicitly if make is/was running tasks in parallel.. Setting bigger hard/soft limit might help

Comment: nproc is set to 2061293 for all users, don't think that's the limit here.

Comment: I should clarify, the soft and hard limits for max user processes (-u) is 2061293.

Comment: Did it emit the error before or after you interrupted the build by typing a Ctrl-C?  If after, then have you considered that the Ctrl-C might have been the cause?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The error occurs and blocks the terminal indefinitely.  In order to cancel, I press Ctrl+C.

Comment: FYI, this occurs on the latest Python 3.10, and 3.11, but not on 3.12.  Problem is that Python 3.12 removed the "imp" module in favor of importlib, but the machine is using Passenger 5.0.x which still depends on imp.

Comment: I'm not following why Passenger's module usage would be relevant to the forward progress of your custom Python build.  And as for the build, are you sure it really blocks indefinitely, or might it just have blocked longer than you thought it reasonable to wait?  Was any work being done?

Comment: Passenger is the reason for the custom build of this version, rather than just using 3.12.0 which installs fine.  Hence, the mention of Passenger.

I'm fairly sure that it's indefinite, I've left it as long as overnight and it just sits there.  Nothing else being run as my user, constantly reproducible at any time.

Comment: FYI, talking to the admins of the machine I'm working on, it seems there may be some sort of process-limiting sorcery going on from their end.  Waiting to hear back, and will close the question if/when that is determined to be the cause.

Comment: Sure enough, it seems that their grsec kernel is causing the issue.  They don't seem to have any way to workaround it at this time, although they're looking into it.